# How to get code to respond to a certain time from the DS3231 RTC?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am trying to make a program that runs when it gets to five in the afternoon, so 17:00:00.

I am using this DS3231 library, but I can't figure out a way to get it to send "Woooopp" to the serial monitor at the specified time.

On the DS3231, the pin labeled SCL is connected to A5 on the Arduino and the pin labeled SDA is connected to A4 on the Arduino.

SCL -> A5
SDA -> A4

My code:

```
#include <DS3231.h>

// Init the DS3231 using the hardware interface
DS3231  rtc (SDA, SCL);

void setup() {
  // Setup Serial connection
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Uncomment the next line if you are using an Arduino Leonardo
  //while (!Serial) {}

  // Initialize the rtc object
  rtc.begin();

  // The following lines can be uncommented to set the date and time
  // rtc.setDOW(SATURDAY);     // Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
  // rtc.setTime(19, 48, 50);     // Set the time to 12:00:00 (24hr format)
  // rtc.setDate(3, 6, 2017);   // Set the date to January 1st, 2014
}

void loop() {
  // Send Day-of-Week
  Serial.print(rtc.getDOWStr());
  Serial.print(" ");

  // Send date
  Serial.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  Serial.print(" -- ");

  // Send time
  Serial.println(rtc.getTimeStr());

  // Wait one second before repeating :)

  if (rtc.getTimeStr() == "19:58:12") {
    Serial.println("Woooopp");
  }
  delay (1000);
}
```

No errors are thrown, however, the code simply does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which RTC library do you use ? It seems to be this one: http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=73

Comment: Yes, I used that one. Sorry I forgot to link it, I will edit the question now.

Comment: Try using a shorter delay. All the other stuff also takes time to run, so you are checking slightly less than once per second. So certain seconds will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that and it worked along with me also declaring the time in a variable beforehand and then comparing that instead. Have a great day!

Comment: When you look at the serial output, is the string you are getting from getTimeStr the same as what you expect?

Comment: You could use the DS3231 RTC built-in alarm function(s) to power-on the Arduino Uno.

Comment: @Delta_G I managed to find out that the problem lay with not declaring a variable to store the current time. Before, I was directly comparing the output from the function to the desired time. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: @MikaelPatel Thank you, I will try to use this as well, to see if it will work more efficiently than the method I found in the end.

Comment: Please, post your own answer to the question, for the benefits of others, and accept it to close the question.

Answer (score -1):

> How to get code to respond to a certain time from the DS3231 RTC?

the easiest is to set up the alarm in rtc.

alternatively, keep reading the rtc until the desired time has passed. not terribly efficient.